# How do I store my sleeping bag for long periods?

Tags: gear, gear-care

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to store my sleeping bag for long periods of time?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/318/what-is-the-best-way-to-store-my-sleeping-bag-for-long-periods-of-time)

We're at the point where we have more than one set of gear.  We use different gear for different hikes.  One of my sleeping bags will only see use once or twice a year at most.  What is the best way to store it so that is is not destroying or damaged during storage?